# Unable to validate my calculations

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble trying to validate my form.
I have written a script based on calculations shown below

```
<script>
var class_let = new Array();
class_let["Class A"]=10;
class_let["Class B"]=20;
class_let["Class C"]=40;
class_let["Class D"]=50; 

function getChargingPrice() {
var price=0;
var theForm = document.forms["Classes"];
var classPrice = theForm.elements["day1"];

if(classPrice.checked==true)
{
   price = class_let[classPrice.value];
}
return price;
}

function calculateTotal() {
var calculatedPrice = getChargingPrice() + 20;

var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
divobj.style.display='block';
divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price $"+calculatedPrice;
}

function hideTotal() {
var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
divobj.style.display='none';
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" id="Classes" onsubmit="return false;">
<b>Select Class:</b>
<select id="classLetter" name="classLetter" onchange="calculateTotal()">
   <option value="Class A">Class A</option>
   <option value="Class B">Class B</option>
   <option value="Class C">Class C</option>
   <option value="Class D">Class D</option>
</select>
<p><b><label for="attendance">Days Attending:</label></b></p>
<td><p><input type="checkbox" id="day1" name="Day One" onclick="calculateTotal()" value="Monday"/> Monday<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="day2" name="Day Two" value="Tuesday"/> Tuesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="day3" name="Day Three" value="Wednesday"/> Wednesday<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="day4" name="Day Four" value="Thursday"/> Thursday<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="day5" name="Day Five" value="Friday"/> Friday<br>
<p><b><label for="cost">Total Cost:</label></b></p>
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
</form>
```

What I have is a drop down list of classes, five check boxes of days and total price function.

How this script is suppose to run is each class (drop down lists) have their own different price amount, but it is added by the amount of days selected or checked. E.g. If I want to select Class B (which is equal to 20) and I select Monday and Wednesday, my script should add 20  + 20 = 40 plus another 20 at the end, with a total of $60.

I haven't written the entire script but my problem is when I check or click on a day, it is not able to give me a total calculation like I described.
I would must appreciate help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see some odd code trying to get the checkbox value, and that it only works for the first checkbox which is Monday. Here are some tips to get you started:

1. I suggest storing two values. One to keep track of the current price based on which class is selected. One to keep track of the price based on the days selected.
2. Calculate and update these prices when any of the input/select elements change.

An example below (you will need to set the onchange attributes on the other 4 checkboxes to execute the `calculateTotal()` function:

```
var class_let = new Array();
class_let["Class A"] = 10;
class_let["Class B"] = 20;
class_let["Class C"] = 40;
class_let["Class D"] = 50;

var classPrice = 0;
var daysPrice = 0;

function setClassPrice() {
    var className = document.getElementById('classLetter').options[selectedIndex].value;
    classPrice = class_let[className];
}

function setDaysPrice() {
    daysPrice = 0;
    var checkbox, i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        checkbox = document.getElementById('day' + i);
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            daysPrice += 20;
        }
    }
}

function calculateTotal() {
    setClassPrice();
    setDaysPrice();

    var calculatedPrice = classPrice + daysPrice;
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display = 'block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total Price $" + calculatedPrice;
}

function hideTotal() {
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with wongcode, also, you should try to avoid using event handlers in the html markup. For example:

```
<input type="radio" onclick = "myFunction()">
```

^ this is just bad practice.

Try to keep JS in it's own file as much as possible. I wasn't exactly sure what you were trying to achieve so I just remade the app in jsfiddle for you with some changes. I would have redone the entire html markup but I don't have time to redo everything. Here is what I made.

http://jsfiddle.net/VodkaTonic/aaDr6/3/

Keep in mind there are a lot of things I would have changed here.